# Phone calls using the mobile network are blocked by your administrator blackberry

Tags: blackberry

BB z10  giving me error of

> phone calls using the mobile network are blocked by your administrator

i also try to flash again with this latest firmware with auto loader. How to solve this issue?.

[image]

Comment: on legacy blackberry devices, with RIM OS, there was a thing, called IT Policy. It is a data block that can be set to a device by BES (BlackBerry Enterprise Server) admin to block/unblock certain device functions. IT Policy cannot be removed via reinstalling firmware. Probably you have the same issue. Check this post: http://support.blackberry.com/kb/articleDetail?ArticleNumber=000014202

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have updated my phone over wifi and its solved my problem.